# postgresql : **ERROR: path element at position 1 is not an integer:**

Tags: json, postgresql-10

I am trying to update a field value in jsonb column with text value present in another column but getting some syntax errors; not getting any solution.

i am trying to swap values of OutgoingVertexid & IncomingVertexId in below JSONB

```
'[
      {
         "Edgeid":10,
         "Weight":100,
         "Active":1,
         "OutgoingVertexid":"",
         "IncomingVertexid":"G",
         "EdgeColor":"Black"
      }
   ]
'
```

so used below code by putting all values OutgoingVertexid & IncomingVertexid value in temp table.

```
UPDATE temp_table 
        SET 
        owner_property = CASE 
                            WHEN owner_outgoing_edge IS NOT NULL 
                                THEN jsonb_set(owner_property, '{OutgoingVertexid}', '""')
                            ELSE 
                                jsonb_set(owner_property, '{OutgoingVertexid}', ''||owner_incoming_edge::jsonb||'') 
                                END;
```

but getting below error:

**ERROR: path element at position 1 is not an integer:**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json value is an array, not a single value. So you need to pick the array element you want to change by including the index in the array you pass to `jsonb_set()`

```
UPDATE temp_table 
  SET owner_property = CASE 
                        WHEN owner_outgoing_edge IS NOT NULL 
                          THEN jsonb_set(owner_property, '{0, OutgoingVertexid}', '""')
                        ELSE 
                          jsonb_set(owner_property, '{0, OutgoingVertexid}', to_jsonb(owner_incoming_edge)) 
                       END
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name...Thanks for your response. As i am beginner to JSON so could not get this solution and to avoid time i just used a below hack ...             UPDATE temp_table 
SET owner_property =      
replace(owner_property::text,'OutgoingVertexid','123')::jsonb;
 
UPDATE temp_table 
SET owner_property = replace(owner_property::text,'IncomingVertexid','OutgoingVertexid')::jsonb;

UPDATE temp_table 
SET owner_property =      
replace(owner_property::text,'123','IncomingVertexid')::jsonb;

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name...if i go with your solution sometimes i am getting "" in my temp_table column while extracting value. How can i check in that case as WHEN owner_outgoing_edge IS NOT NULL  is not getting passed.